# Save author posts as in pending review - block users updating their posts

Tags: admin, post-status

How can I let the users (author, editor, contributor etc) to edit their own posts but not to update them, just keep them as in "pending for review" so I can decide if it's ok to publish or not. By default these posts submitted by users are "pending for review" but once I decide to publish the post, the author can edit the post again and publish it without been held for moderation.

Is there any way to get the same post pending for review every time the author edit them ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How about the [Revisionary plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revisionary/)? It allows you to set pages as "save as pending" after making changes to an existing published page, so that your changes are saved as a draft but not yet pushed live.

You can also use it to help customize user roles - so if you want to allow someone to be able to edit content, but not let them hit the publish button without approval, Revisionary lets you set that up.

Hope that helps!